# How can get MergeArea by PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

With Excel Com: i can get `MergeArea` by :

```
oCell->MergeArea;
```

I want convert Excel Com to PHPExcel,
But Does PhpExcel support get `MergeArea`?
Or can get number rows, columns merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel maintains a list of all merge ranges on the worksheet object, and you can retrieve that list using

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getMergeCells();
```

which will return a simple array containing all the defined merge ranges in that worksheet.

If you want to tell if a particular cell is part of a merge range, then you can use

```
$cell->isInMergeRange();
```

Which will return a simple boolean true/false

```
$cell->isMergeRangeValueCell();
```

Will return a boolean true/false if this is the topleft cell in a merge range

```
$cell->getMergeRange();
```

Will return a string showing the merge range that a cell is a part of, or a boolean false if it isn't part of a merge range

Comment: i get a error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Cell::isInMergeRange()

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you running? The code is [definitely there](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php#L497)

Comment: i using  ver1.7.9